# Nested ListView in wicket throwing IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: listview, nested, wicket

I have a nested ListView in wicket which for some reason is throwing an IndexOutOfBoundsException. Here is the relevant markup:

```
<table>
  <tr wicket:id="dataRow">
    <td wicket:id="dataCell"><span wicket:id="dataContent"></span></td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

and the relevant code:

```
    ListView<User> dataRow = new ListView<User>("dataRow", new AbstractReadOnlyModel<List<User>>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        public List<User> getObject() {
            ...
            return getUsers(itemOffset, c, filter, sc, isDescending );
            // returns a List<User> of row objects
        }

    }) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<User> item) {
            // list of <TD>s
            ListView<String> dataCell = new ListView<String>("dataCell",new AbstractReadOnlyModel<List<String>>() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public List<String> getObject() {
                    return getColumnValues(item.getModelObject());
                    // gets a list of strings to display from the User object
                }
            }) {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                protected void populateItem(ListItem<String> stringItem) {
                    Label dataContent = new Label("dataContent", stringItem.getModel());
                    dataContent.setRenderBodyOnly(true);
                    stringItem.add(dataContent);
                }
            };
            dataCell.setReuseItems(true);
            item.add(dataCell);
        }
    };
    dataRow.setReuseItems(true);
    add(dataRow);
```

No Ajax refresh or anything has been done (yet), but I get an exception at the first rendering already:

```
Unexpected RuntimeException

Last cause: Index: 10, Size: 10
WicketMessage: Exception in rendering component: [Component id = dataContent]

Stacktrace

Root cause:

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
 at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.list.ListItemModel.getObject(ListItemModel.java:59)
 at org.apache.wicket.Component.getDefaultModelObject(Component.java:1605)
 at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.list.ListItem.getModelObject(ListItem.java:92)
 at myadmin.web.panels.TableViewPanel$3$1.getObject(TableViewPanel.java:156)
 at myadmin.web.panels.TableViewPanel$3$1.getObject(TableViewPanel.java:1)
 at org.apache.wicket.Component.getDefaultModelObject(Component.java:1605)
 at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.list.ListView.getModelObject(ListView.java:643)
 at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.list.ListItemModel.getObject(ListItemModel.java:59)
 at org.apache.wicket.Component.getDefaultModelObject(Component.java:1605)
 at org.apache.wicket.Component.getDefaultModelObjectAsString(Component.java:1633)
 at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label.onComponentTagBody(Label.java:131)
 at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:71)
 at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2529)
 at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebComponent.onRender(WebComponent.java:56)
 at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2359)
 at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2287)
 at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1392)
 at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1557)
 at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1532)
 at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1487)
 at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:71)
 at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2529)
 at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1496)
 at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2359)
 at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2287)
 at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.list.ListView.renderItem(ListView.java:584)
 at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.list.ListView.renderChild(ListView.java:573)
 at org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractRepeater.onRender(AbstractRepeater.java:101)
 at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2359)
 at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2287)
 at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1392)
 at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1557)
 at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1532)
 at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1487)
 at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:71)
 at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2529)
 at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1496)
 at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2359)
```

...

I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using a LoadableDetachableModel instead of AbstractReadOnlyModel for "dataRow"'s model, it seems the returned list is changing during rendering.

Comment: Thanks! That did it! :)